# How to enable id for label tag when using django forms?

Tags: html, django

I'm using django forms, looking suggestion how to enable id for label tag?

i could see id by default enabled for all tags except label.

Comment: It is not entirely clear to me what you aim to achieve. Can you provide an example with the expected output?

Comment: current output: <label for="id_field1">Field1</label>
Looking for <label for="id_field1" id="id_field1">Field1</label>

Comment: You can't give the label the same `id` as the input field it is connected to if the input field is using `id="id_field1"`

Comment: @Nani: but the `for=""` needs to refer to the `<input>` element to which the label is referring.

Comment: Here is the example

File: Test.html
{{form.as_table}}



Output:

<tr>
    <th><label for="id_name">Name:</label></th>
    <td><input id="id_name" name="name" type="text" /></td>
</tr>\n

i'm not seeing label id for the Label "Name:", when form load how can we enable attribute id for Label

Comment: @Nani, Why do you need `id` in label? What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score -1):

From what you have said I'm going to assume that when you say "tag" you mean an HTML element (e.g. `<input>`, `<label>`, `<p>`) and you want Django to automatically insert an `id` attribute in to the `label` attached to your form input fields.

There are two problems with this:

**Where will Django get the `id` from?** Labels are created from the field name, or if you supply one, a string parameter passed to the field in your model. Here's the [example from the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#label):

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    name = forms.CharField(label='Your name')
```

You cannot supply an `id` for the label.

**`id` values must be unique in the whole document.** If you give the label the same `id` as the field it is attached to you will violate this rule of uniquness.

As NKSM commented, why do you need an `id` on the label? If you can provide some more information as to what you are trying to do we might be able to help with an alternative solution.